# How can i create custom channel for the websphere MQ and how to configure with java client program

Tags: java, ibm-mq

How can i create custom channel for the websphere MQ and how to configure with java client program ,

Which channel i want to create for send message to websphereMQ (Server-connection-Channel is ok)

Comment: Please checkout documentation and examples about websphere MQ on ibm sites.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a Server connection (SVRCONN) channel for your client application to send messages to a WebSphere MQ Queue. It does not matter whether the application is developed in Java, C, C# etc.

You can either use MQ Explorer (GUI) or RUNMQSC(cmd line) for creating a SVRCONN channel. In MQExplorer right click on "Channels" and select "Server-Connection channel" menu. A wizard pops up which will guide you to create a channel.

You can also use "RUNMQSC" command line tool. From a command prompt run "runmqsc " which opens a MQ shell. In the shell run the below command (replace <> with your preferred names) in simplest form.

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(<some channel name>) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
```

You can also specify a number of other attributes for this command which described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/sc11010_.htm)

A number of Java/JMS samples are shipped with MQ. SimplePTP.java explains how to use a SVRCONN to connect to a queue manager and send/receive messages.

Comment: Is there any rule of naming server-connection channel. I created one but it fails to start and in Inactive status.

Comment: It's a convention to use upper case letters for MQ object names. For server connection channels you include application name and queue manager name and SVRCONN at the end if you like. For example "FINAPP.QM1.SVRCONN" where FINAPP points to the application using the server connection channel and QM1 is the queue manager name. When you create a server connection channel it will be in inactive state. It goes into running state when a client application using this channel connects to queue manager.

Comment: In this line I pass host IP, port of queue manager and the channel name. new PCFMessageAgent(host, Integer.parseInt(port), channelName); But I get MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.

Comment: 2035 reason code is sent down when the user under whom the application is running does not have authority to connect to queue manager or open queue/topic. You need to configure your queue manager to let your application connect.

Comment: I set the permissions and I'm able to run sample program MQIVP. But with PCFMessageAgent I get the error : com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
 at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.open(MQDestination.java:323) And I have linked the MQ log at http://imgur.com/a/2eZpC